# Which one is Better from in DATE_FORMATE() OR MONTH(),YEAR()

Tags: mysql, datetime, query-optimization

I have to get a records/count on monthly basis.
There is no of ways to do ---

1

```
SELECT COUNT(1)AS approved FROM lu_registration 
WHERE MONTH(approved_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(approved_date)=YEAR(NOW());
```

2

```
SELECT COUNT(1)AS approved FROM lu_registration 
WHERE DATE_FORMATE(approved_date, '%Y-%m')=DATE_FORMATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m');
```

3

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(approved_date)=MONTH(NOW()) 
AND YEAR(approved_date)=YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 END)AS approved FROM lu_registration;
```

4

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMATE(approved_date, '%Y-%m')=DATE_FORMATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
 THEN 1 END)AS approved FROM lu_registration;
```

Which one is best.

Actual Senerio:
There is a month filter by which we select month,and get as 04-2016. So that we can use date_format (%m-%y) or month=04 & year=2016 to match for getting records.but which one is performance wise better

Actual query to optimize is:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN status='A' AND MONTH(approved_date)=04
AND YEAR(approved_date)=2016 THEN 1 END)AS approved, COUNT(CASE WHEN status='D' AND MONTH(reject_date)=04 
AND YEAR(reject_date)=2016 THEN 1 END)AS rejected FROM lu_registration;
```

Here is approved_date & reject_date two different column or approved user also be rejected

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to count records in a date range. With respect, none of your suggested queries are efficient. None can exploit a MySQL index on your `approved_date` column. None of them is [*sargeable*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) That's going to harm performance, especially as your application adds records with dates going back years.

Instead, you need a query of the form

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS approved
   FROM table
  WHERE approved_date >= <<<00:00 on first date>>>
    AND approved_date <  <<<00:00 on day after last date>>>
```

This can do an [index scan](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/) on an index on your approved_date column.

So, now the trick needed is obtaining correct values for `<<<00:00 on first date>>` and `<<<00:00 on day after last date>>>` from `NOW()`. Here's what you do.

1. `LAST_DAY(NOW())` gives 00:00 on the last day of the present month.
2. `LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY` gives 00:00 on the first day of next month.
3. `LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` gives 00:00 on the first day of the present month.

So, your query becomes

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS approved
   FROM lu_registration
  WHERE approved_date >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND approved_date <  LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

It chooses the correct date range, and, it runs fast.

(Notice I used `COUNT(*)` in place of your `COUNT(1)`. That is because `COUNT(*)` is the common way of counting records. Sometimes query planner modules in RDMS software optimize it specially.)

Comment: Great answer, great explanation, plus I learned a new word! Thank you! :-)

Comment: There is a month filter by which we select month,and retrieve as 04-2016. So that we can use date_format (%m-%y) or month=04 & year=2016 to get records.but which one is performance wise better

Comment: @Zigri2612 - A range (that can use an index) is always better than any kind of expression.

Comment: Any `WHERE` expression involving  `f(column)` will perform pretty much the same as any other. They all will perform very badly indeed because they are not sargeable. To satisfy such a query the MySQL server software must examine every row in the database. That's called a full table scan or maybe a full index scan. Slow.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN status='A' AND MONTH(approved_date)=04
    AND YEAR(approved_date)=2016 THEN 1 END)AS approved, COUNT(CASE WHEN status='D' AND MONTH(reject_date)=04 
    AND YEAR(reject_date)=2016 THEN 1 END)AS rejected FROM lu_registration;

Answer (score 1):

I think first one is Better--

```
SELECT COUNT(1)AS approved FROM lu_registration 
WHERE MONTH(approved_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(approved_date)=YEAR(NOW());
```